# Is the force due to mass flow proportional to the square of the mass velocity?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to calculate the force on a surface due to some flow of water against that surface- for simplicity, assume that the mass flow vector is orthogonal to the surface.

Using dimensional analysis, I found that $F \propto MV$, where $M$ is the mass flow rate in kg/s and V is the velocity of the flow in m/s. However, $M$ could be expressed as $M = \rho A V$, where $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the flow and $\rho$ is the density of the liquid. So I end up with $F \propto \rho A V^2$. Is this correct? If so, why is the relationship not linear?

Comment: $M = \rho A V$.